# iOS App help page displays old version number

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Trying to get help for another [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235197/login-to-ios-app-spools-forever) I encountered this minor issue:

On the app store the version number for the app is `1.1.0`:

[image: app store]

However on the `help` screen the version displayed is incorrectly shown as `1.0.1`:

[image: help page]

This is also true for pulling down the menu (I think):

[image: menu swipe down]

Comment: Wow! It says "1.0.1 05/13/20141.1.0" above the menu, so it's a "1.0.1" before the date and a "1.1.0" after the date!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in whatever the next prod build is.  Some version numbers in the app come from a weird version text file that is touched when the app is built.  I don't like it and will probably change that later, but it's not a big deal.

More to the point, the build server grows the file by echoing the new version and date and appending it to the file.  Someone in a reorg accidentally deleted the newline at the end of the file resulting in two lines crammed together that you see in the menu.

Comment: Awesome answer, love those small but juicy details! :)

Comment: Sounds good. I love the description "weird version text file"